# При редактировании ячейки автоматически меняется цвет, но при отмене изменений не меняется цвет на белый Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Написал скрипт, который при редактировании ячейки автоматически меняется цвет, но при отмене изменений не меняется цвет на белый в Google Sheets. Вот пример кода, что нужно добавить, чтобы он заработал?

```
function onEdit() {

  var sheetsToWatch = ['кафедра', 'преподаватели'];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var matchFound = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
  if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatch[i])) matchFound = true;
    }
  if (!matchFound) return;

  var rowColLabel = 
  sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),cell.getColumn()).setBackground('#faec15'); // #faec15 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не нужно добавлять. Это особенность платформы. К сожалению, это общее упущение приложения, либо какие-то специфические ограничения, которые известны только разработчику ‍♂️.